Android Studio - Allow WebView to upload files with inapp view
i am trying again to ask my question starting back from the start... i use WebView with inapp sites view to open my projects websites and everythings seems ok (only the graphics layout have to be fixed) but when i am trying to upload a file from my html form in  nothing happened... the button seems dead... hope someone can help me, i only know people who don't be as good as me in programming... i also have tryied to use AdvancedWebView but i am unable to end the gradle building stage.
Solve this problem or help me to find a solution.

Have solved with this https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView make way through the configuration but now have another bigger problem... file selector is opening but when i confirm the files came back null...
